# Iterate over strings that ".StartsWith" without using LINQ

Tags: c#, performance, linq, uwp, hashtable

I'm building a custom textbox to enable mentioning people in a social media context. This means that I detect when somebody types "@" and search a list of contacts for the string that follows the "@" sign.
The easiest way would be to use LINQ, with something along the lines of `Members.Where(x => x.Username.StartsWith(str)`. The problem is that the amount of potential results can be extremely high (up to around 50,000), and performance is extremely important in this context.

What alternative solutions do I have? Is there anything similar to a dictionary (a hashtable based solution) but that would allow me to use `Key.StartsWith` without itterating over every single entry? If not, what would be the fastest and most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: You don't have to load them all up at once. You definitely aren't going to show a dropdown with 50000 results, only maybe like 10 max. So just search through your list and get the first 10 or so that match. Also of course, make sure the search is async, and the list is ordered (or even, alphabetized into a dictionary maybe) to speed up searches.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie StartWith is not good enough with large datasets especially when it needs to be called at every key stroke.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to show a dropdown of 50000? If you can limit your dropdown, you can for example just display the first 10.

```
var filteredMembers = new List<MemberClass>
foreach(var member in Members)
{
    if(member.Username.StartWith(str)) filteredMembers.Add(member);
    if(filteredMembers >= 10) break;
}
```

**Alternatively:**
You can try storing all your member's usernames into a Trie in addition to your collection. That should give you a better performance then looping through all 50000 elements.
Assuming your usernames are unique, you can store your member information in a dictionary and use the usernames as the key.
This is a tradeoff of memory for performance of course.

Comment: A [DAWG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_acyclic_finite_state_automaton) would be another approach one might consider instead of a trie.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear where the data is stored in the first place. Are all the names in memory or in a database?

In case you store them in database, you can just use the `StartsWith` approach in the ORM, which would translate to a `LIKE` query on the DB, which would just do its job. If you enable full text on the column, you could improve the performance even more.

Now supposing all the names are already in memory. Remember the computer CPU is extremely fast so even looping through 50 000 entries takes just a few moments.
 `StartsWith` method is optimized and it will return `false` as soon as it encounters a non-matching character. Finding the ones that actually match should be pretty fast. But you can still do better.

As others suggest, you could build a trie to store all the names and be able to search for matches pretty fast, but there is a disadvantage - building the trie requires you to read all the names and create the whole data structure which is complex. Also you would be restricted only to a given set of characters and a unexpected character would have to be dealt with separately.

You can however group the names into "buckets". First start with the first character and create a dictionary with the character as a key and a list of names as the value. Now you effectively narrowed every following search approximately 26 times (supposing English alphabet). But don't have to stop there - you can perform this on another level, for the second character in each group. And then third and so on.

With each level you are effectively narrowing each group significantly and the search will be much faster afterwards. But there is of course the up-front cost of building the data structure, so you always have to find the right trade-off for you. More work up-front = faster search, less work = slower search.

Finally, when the user types, with each new letter she narrows the target group. Hence, you can always maintain the set of relevant names for the current input and cut it down with each successive keystroke. This will prevent you from having to go from the beginning each time and will improve the efficiency significantly.

Answer (score 0):

### Use `BinarySearch`

This is a pretty normal case, assuming that the data are stored in-memory, and here is a pretty standard way to handle it.

1. Use a normal `List<string>`. You don't need a HashTable or a SortedList. However, an `IEnumerable<string>` won't work; it has to be a list.
2. Sort the list beforehand (using LINQ, e.g. `OrderBy( s => s)`), e.g. during initialization or when retrieving it. This is the key to the whole approach.
3. Find the index of the best match using [BinarySearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Because the list is sorted, a binary search can find the best match very quickly and without scanning the whole list like Select/Where might.
4. Take the first N entries after the found index. Optionally you can truncate the list if not all N entries are a decent match, e.g. if someone typed "AZ" and there are only one or two items before "BA."

Example:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Find(List<string> list, string firstFewLetters, int maxHits)
{
    var startIndex = list.BinarySearch(firstFewLetters);

    //If negative, no match. Take the 2's complement to get the index of the closest match.
    if (startIndex < 0)
    {
        startIndex = ~startIndex;  
    }

    //Take maxHits items, or go till end of list
    var endIndex = Math.Min( 
                             startIndex + maxHits - 1, 
                             list.Count-1 
                           ); 

    //Enumerate matching items
    for ( int i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++ )
    {
        var s = list[i];
        if (!s.StartsWith(firstFewLetters)) break;  //This line is optional
        yield return s;
    }
}
```

Click [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/31AkTu) for a working sample on DotNetFiddle.